# NetBeans 8.2 freeze on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans

Frequently NetBeans 8.2 freeze on Ubuntu 17.04 with the following error:

> GLib:ERROR:../../../../glib/ghash.c:373:g_hash_table_lookup_node:assertion failed: (hash_table->ref_count > 0) /home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/nbexec: riga 470:  4898 Annullato               (core dump creato) "/usr/bin/java" -Djdk.home="/usr" -classpath "/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/boot.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ja.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_pt_BR.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ru.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_zh_CN.jar:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar" -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root="/home/caiofior/.netbeans" -Dnetbeans.dirs="/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/nb:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/ergonomics:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/ide:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/extide:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/java:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/apisupport:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/webcommon:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/websvccommon:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/enterprise:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/mobility:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/profiler:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/python:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/php:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/identity:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/harness:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/cnd:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/cndext:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/dlight:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/groovy:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/extra:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/javacard:/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/javafx:" -Dnetbeans.home="/home/caiofior/netbeans-8.2/platform" '-Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade' '-Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense' '-Xmx1024m' '-client' '-Xss2m' '-Xms32m' '-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true' '-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true' '-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true' '-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true' '-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true' -DaddExports:java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/com.sun.beans.editors=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/sun.awt.im=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk=ALL-UNNAMED -DaddExports:java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="/home/caiofior/.netbeans/8.2/var/log/heapdump.hprof" -splash:"/home/caiofior/.cache/netbeans/8.2/splash.png" org.netbeans.Main --cachedir "/home/caiofior/.cache/netbeans/8.2" --userdir "/home/caiofior/.netbeans/8.2" "--branding" "nb" 0<&0

Answer (score 4):

Comment one row in file

/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties

Form

```
 #
 # The following line specifies the assistive technology classes 
 # that should be loaded into the Java VM when the AWT is initailized.
 # Specify multiple classes by separating them with commas.
 # Note: the line below cannot end the file (there must be at
 # a minimum a blank line following it).
 #
 assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```

To

```
#
# The following line specifies the assistive technology classes 
# that should be loaded into the Java VM when the AWT is initailized.
# Specify multiple classes by separating them with commas.
# Note: the line below cannot end the file (there must be at
# a minimum a blank line following it).
#
#assistive_technologies=org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper
```